# Selecting <p> Descendant using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How come all the result have the default Black color? Non of the rules were accepted! Is this because `<p>` is not allowed to have descendants? Where would such rule be listed? Thanks.

Example

HTML

```
<div id="id1">
    <p>...some text...</p>
    <p>
          <p> nested p </p>
          <span> nested span 1 </span>
    </p>
    <span> nested span 2 </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
p>p {color:red;}
p>span {color:yellow;}
p p {color:green;}
p span {color:blue;}
```

Comment: Uh, there is an "Edit Summary" field for you to type that when editing your question.

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks. I should have used that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this because `<p>` is not allowed to have descendants

No, it is because `<p>` is not allowed to have descendants that are `<p>` elements (among others).

> Where would such rule be listed?

In [the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) (under "Content Model").

You may find that it useful to test your code with [a markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/).